# How do I subscribe to a Twist message in micro-ROS

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the ping_pong example as a starting point to create a subscriber for Twist messages.

I can't find any examples of how to do this, and being new to C I am getting a bit overwhelmed. So I'm hoping you can guide me and not get too frustrated with me.

I don't get any errors when I build the project, and I can successfully flash the ESP32, but none of the print() debug messages are shown when I run the monitor.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
#include <rcl/rcl.h>
#include <rcl/error_handling.h>
#include <rclc/rclc.h>
#include <rclc/executor.h>

// #include <std_msgs/msg/header.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/twist.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "driver/gpio.h"

//#ifdef ESP_PLATFORM
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
//#endif

#define STRING_BUFFER_LEN 50

#define RCCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){printf("Failed status on line %d: %d. Aborting.\n",__LINE__,(int)temp_rc); vTaskDelete(NULL);}}
#define RCSOFTCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){printf("Failed status on line %d: %d. Continuing.\n",__LINE__,(int)temp_rc);}}

#define R_WHEEL_FORWARD_GPIO CONFIG_R_WHEEL_FORWARD_GPIO
#define R_WHEEL_BACKWARD_GPIO CONFIG_R_WHEEL_BACKWARD_GPIO
#define R_WHEEL_PWM_GPIO CONFIG_R_WHEEL_PWM_GPIO

#define L_WHEEL_FORWARD_GPIO CONFIG_L_WHEEL_FORWARD_GPIO
#define L_WHEEL_BACKWARD_GPIO CONFIG_L_WHEEL_BACKWARD_GPIO
#define L_WHEEL_PWM_GPIO CONFIG_L_WHEEL_PWM_GPIO


rcl_subscription_t cmd_vel_subscriber;


geometry_msgs__msg__Twist incoming_twist;

struct twist_message {
    double lin_x;
    double lin_y;
    double lin_z;
    double angle_x;
    double angle_y;
    double angle_z;
};

void twist_subscription_callback(const void * msgin)
{
    const geometry_msgs__msg__Twist * msg = (const geometry_msgs__msg__Twist *)msgin;

    //Deal with the twist message recieved here
    printf("I got a twist message");
}



void appMain(void *argument)
{
    printf("Starting appMain");
    printf("Hello Simon");
    rcl_allocator_t allocator = rcl_get_default_allocator();
    rclc_support_t support;

    // create init_options
    RCCHECK(rclc_support_init(&support, 0, NULL, &allocator));

    // create node
    rcl_node_t node;
    RCCHECK(rclc_node_init_default(&node, "robot_motor_node", "", &support));


    // Create a best effort cmd_vel subscriber
    RCCHECK(rclc_subscription_init_best_effort(&cmd_vel_subscriber, &node,
        ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, String), "/microROS/robot_cmd_vel"));


    // Create executor
    rclc_executor_t executor;
    RCCHECK(rclc_executor_init(&executor, &support.context, 3, &allocator));
    RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_subscription(&executor, &cmd_vel_subscriber, &incoming_twist,
        &twist_subscription_callback, ON_NEW_DATA));
    
    // RCCHECK(rcl_subscription_fini(&cmd_vel_subscriber, &node));
    // RCCHECK(rcl_node_fini(&node));

    while(1){
        rclc_executor_spin_some(&executor, RCL_MS_TO_NS(10));
        usleep(10000);
    }

    RCCHECK(rcl_subscription_fini(&cmd_vel_subscriber, &node));
    RCCHECK(rcl_node_fini(&node));

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369403/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-twist-message-in-micro-ros/) by [IonCoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/67726/ioncoder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, check [this](https://github.com/pablogs9/kobuki_esp32_micro_ros/blob/96a65c9156edbc560c81849c45aecb680518b7e0/main/kobuki_microros.c#L102) code. It is a full demo that controls a Kobuki robot with an ESP32 and micro-ROS, and it uses the Twist subscriber to move to micro-ROS robot.

You also can find some explanations about this demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PX0NUnc4OLo).

If you have more questions, please open an issue in one of our Github repos.

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2021-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IonCoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/67726/ioncoder/) on 2021-01-13**:
@Pablogs Thank you, I think that is probably just what I need to get me going.

I will look at it tonight and then come back and accept your answer.

Thanks again.

**Comment by [IonCoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/67726/ioncoder/) on 2021-01-13**:
The code you pointed to worked well the first time. I took the publisher code out, so I can understand one thing at a time and I didn't break anything :-)